# Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. even after including the CORS support

Tags: apache, rest, spring-boot, web, cors

I am trying to write an Api in spring boot and am trying to access it using frontend I have written.
I have added the Cors support, still I am getting this error:
*

> Failed to load http://localhost:8080/: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

My Cors support in main file is:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

I am using apache server for frontend.

Can sopmeone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To enable CORS in spring-boot you need to add the following filter class in your spring-boot application.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {

public SimpleCorsFilter() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "WWW-Authenticate");
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
}
```

Comment: Actually I am following spring Boot guides. But I am not able to figure out whats wrong with the code? https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework